# Angular 5 HttpClient corrupts binary downloads

Tags: angular5

When downloading a binary file from a remove server using the angular 5 http client the file is consistently corrupted. I've been unable to find resources related to this version of the client for resolving this problem. Setting the response type to either 'arraybuffer' or 'blob' does not resolve the issue.

**What is the proper way to download a binary file in Angular 5 and convert it to a Uint8Array?**

My current code is as follows

```
this.data = this.http.get(_.get(record, 'href', ''), {
                observe: 'events',
                reportProgress: true,
                responseType: 'blob'
            }))
        .do(httpEvent => {
            if (httpEvent.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress) {
                this.percent.next((httpEvent.loaded / httpEvent.total) * 100);
            }
        })
        .switchMap(httpEvent => {
            if (httpEvent.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
                return this.blobToArrayBuffer(httpEvent.body);
            }

            return Observable.of(new ArrayBuffer(0));
        })
        .map(buffer => {
            const buff = new Uint8Array(buffer);
            ... // Decode buffer here
        }


...

private blobToArrayBuffer(blob: Blob): Observable<ArrayBuffer> {
    return Observable.create(obs => {
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = () => obs.next(fileReader.result);
        fileReader.onloadend = () => obs.complete();

        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    });
}
```

I don't see anything obviously wrong with the response headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: ...
x-amz-request-id: ...
Date: Tue, 23 Jan 2018 18:25:07 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Jan 2018 22:25:33 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
ETag: ...
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
Content-Length: 148341
```

Any insight would be helpful.